# How to start numbering at 0. in Powerpoint?

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint

I would like to create a numbered list in Powerpoint that starts at *0.* instead of *1.* Is this possible (maybe with VBA)? Or can I only manually mimic at *0.* the lay-out of the numbered list that starts at *1.*?

[image]

[Powerpoint in Office 365]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to do this, even with VBA. If you try to set the bullet StartValue property to 0 with the example code below (make sure you have selected a bulleted shape on the slide) you'll get an error:

```
Activewindow.Selection.TextRange2.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.StartValue = 0
```

See this article which attempts to explain the logic in this design decision:

https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Microsoft-PowerPoint-forbid-starting-a-numbered-list-from-zero

In addition, PowerPoint doesn't support decimal numbering e.g. 1.0, 1.1, 1.2

Answer (score 9):

## no solution but workaround

Start your list with `10` instead of `0` and cover the left digit with a white box. If you need more than nine items, start the list with `100`.

## instructions

### create list

[image]

### start with `10`

[image]

### fill list

[image]

### insert white box

[image]

### voila

[image]